# How do you get good line spacing with lpr?

Tags: unix, lpr

I'm using lpr with the following flags:

```
lpr -o cpi=12 -o lpi=8 -o page-left=36 -o page-top=36 -o page-bottom=36
```

But the lines appear too close together. But if I decrease lpi to 6 or something, the font just gets taller. What I really want is control over the amount of space between the lines.

My makeshift solution is to insert blank lines in the document using `sed G`, but ideally I would like to achieve 1.5 line spacing instead of full double-spaced. Is this possible?

Comment: Where is the right place to ask this question?

Comment: It's a good question. What is generating the printer input? Are you sending RAW or using a PPD?